# Background isn't filling the entire screen

Tags: css, background-image

How do I get the gradient image to fill the entire screen?

Right now it is cut off.

To reproduce, click on the blue play image then scroll down.

That is all I am trying to do, have the image fill the entire screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/1tm4fujo/

```
 .containerb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(teal, teal);
  background-size: 165px 165px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `#0000` is a valid color identifier? Also, in your fiddle, for me it fills the screen. Which browser/OS did you see it fail in?

Comment: 100% sure. https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa

Comment: Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/csUjWb2.png Also updated image on the screen.

Comment: Again, that's not what I'm getting (FF/Chrome/MacOS). https://imgur.com/a/dLZ25XJ

Comment: How am I seeing something different?

Comment: Look Here: https://i.imgur.com/ISPDIju.png

Comment: position: absolute class. I changed it to: position: relative. But now, how is the purple column removed? https://jsfiddle.net/xy9h6dsg/

Answer (score 0):

It is your `position: absolute` class. I changed it to: `position: relative` and its full height. The tiny purple column is from `<div class="tcell">`, you should probably hide that similar to `containera` class.
[image]

Comment: How do I hide the purple? https://jsfiddle.net/xy9h6dsg/ Were you able to figure that out in the code?

Comment: its your tcell class.  Honestly looks like you can remove that div or class. Or you could hide it when blue button is clicked in javascript